# I have a form with required fields for email and password, and it was working fine. However, now it's not working as expected. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, email, button, input

I was creating the bellow code using vscode and I tried it out the first time and I didn't input anything it said I had to input something but as I tried it again it didn't work. I am trying to make a Login page which either when logged in leads to another page or a sign in page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    <style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #141b2d;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #1d273b;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #00a8e8;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

label {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

input[type="email"],
input[type="password"] {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #2a3b5d;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1d273b;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: #8da9c4;
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f5a623;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #f7941d;
}
#text1{
    text-align: center;
}



    </style>
   
</head>
<body>
  <div class="login-container">
    <h1>SmartLedger Login</h1>
    <form>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
      <button type="submit" id="my2Button">Login</button>
      <body id="text1">
        or if you don't have an account
      </body>
      <button type="submit" id="myButton">Signup</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

    <script>

        var button = document.getElementById("myButton");
      
        button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            let url = 'Signup.html'
            window.location.href = url
        });
       
        var button = document.getElementById("my2Button");

        button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            let url = 'payement.html'
            window.location.href = url
        });
      </script>
      
</body>
</html>
```

tried to make the textbox compulsory and it wasn't

Comment: You can't have a body tag inside your other body tag so get rid of `<body id="text1">`

Comment: Change `button.addEventListener("click"` to `button.addEventListener("submit"`

Comment: changing it to submit doesnt work as it resets and doesnt redirect you to the next page

Comment: Works in your example above

Answer (score 1):

I believe **required** attribute only works when submitting the form.
You should probably change **click** event to **submit** event

Like below:

```
button.addEventListener("submit", function() { ... });
```

Comment: I tried it but still doesnt fully work as it resets and doesnt redirect you. I added the full code above

Answer (score 0):

Each `<html>` tag should contain only 1 `<body>` tag

Inside your form you have

```
<body id="text1">
   or if you don't have an account
</body>
```

I bet that's probably should be just `<div> or <p>` instead of `<body>`

Comment: Completely didn't see that ty but it still doesn't work. Will i need to add a check that checks for empty lines or is it something else?

Comment: For me both login and password are required to fill
Did u wrapped this whole content with <html>your code</html>

Comment: It worked once then stopped. I added the whole code above